# Scriptures defining 'Kayavyuha' in Yoga that can nullify karmas quicly

Tags: karma, yoga, sanskrit, vivekananda, patanjali

There is a siddhi in yoga called Kaya-Vyuha. I read recently about it.

Yogi, after attaining this siddhi can present at multiple places with different bodies. **The purpose of such manifestations is to nullify her karma so quickly.** When I learned about it, I found two potential sources.

1. In the commentary of Vivekananda on Pathajali Yoga sutras

> With a view to exhausting their Karma quickly, Yogis create
> Kāya-vyuha, or groups of bodies, in which to work it out. For all
> these bodies they create minds from egoism. These are called "created
> minds", in contradistinction to their original minds.
>
> [[4,4:INDEPENDENCE, Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms, The Complete Works of
> Swami Vivekananda]](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/Patanjali%27s_Yoga_Aphorisms_-_Independence)

2. [In Shandilya Upanishad of Atharvaveda](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shandilya-upanishad-of-atharvaveda/d/doc217052.html)

> By fixing it on his own (Self), one acquires the knowledge of Puruṣa;
> on the navel, he attains a knowledge of the kāya-vyūha (mystical
> arrangement of all the particles of the body so as to enable a person
> to wear out his whole karma in one life): on the well of the throat,
> freedom from hunger and thirst arises: on the Kūrma nādi (which is
> situated in the well of the throat), a firmness (of concentration)
> takes place.
>
> [Chapter 1]

And a [verse in Pathanjali yoga sutras](https://yogastudies.org/sutra/yoga-sutra-chapter-3-verse-29/) uses the word KayaVyuha which says the same as the second quote.

But, if you observe, none of the scripture explicitly defines kayavyuha. Although Vivekananda told what is kayavyuha, it is not explicitly present in verse. And the other two sources do not define what kayavyuha siddhi is.

In this context, I want to know the name of scripture that contains the explicit definition of the kayavyuha siddhi that the quotes told. Which scripture contains the definition of the KayaVyuha siddhi?

Note: if possible, please provide along with the corresponding Sanskrit verse that explains the siddhi.